# Why is the maximum target not (2^256 - 1)?

Tags: difficulty, difficulty-retargetting

I'm reading the [Difficulty](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Difficulty) page on the Bitcoin wiki.

Why is the maximum target `0x00000000FFFF0…` instead of `(2^256 - 1)` (i.e. `0xFFFFFFFFFFFF…`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the maximum target was 2<sup>256</sup>-1, every candidate block would be a valid block.

As even the CPU miner in Bitcoin's first software release was capable of doing 100 kH/s or more, this would have led to a very rough start of the chain, with 1000s of blocks produced per second until the difficulty adjusted.

Because of that reason, the maximum target was probably set to a level that would guarantee not too frequent blocks after genesis.